# MInecraft: Ftb/Techic, Cables not connecting to ME Controller

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

My problem is that when I place down my [ME controller](http://ftbwiki.org/ME_Controller) the Leadstone energy cables and industrialcraft cables don't connect to it, as shown in the picture below.

They were connecting earlier though and nothing has changed since.

[image: Here is a picture of it:]

Comment: Tried replacing the energy conduits?

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe hit it (right click) with a wrench? This will cause the cable to specificaly not connect to any adjacent blocks.

Comment: Didnt work already tryed it, It did fix itself though (after a reload of the world a couple of times) but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your future builds!